# Combine Angular2 with Filter Products animations

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, mixitup

Is it possible to combine Angular2 with MixItUp ? Or, is there any native solution to do that in Angular2 ?

My purpose is to do an eCommerce WebApp. I want to filter my products with some animaitons.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, i have not research about it since this time...